# form submission without submit

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, radio-button

I have a form which has `radio buttons` and I want to submit that form without using submit button. I want to use AJAX calls. I used a piece of javascriptcode to make the radio buttons uncheckable. I want to use AJAX in the same page i used id attribute for the `uncheck` part.
I need to send AJAX request to another PHP page when any changes occur to the form I am wondering what should I do how to write AJAX calls for form submission do I need to use them in the radio button area or I have to use it on the whole form once a simple example will help me a lot, here is my radio button part

```
    <?php


    for($i=0 ;$i<20;$i++){

       echo" <input type='radio' class='radio-button' name='{$i}'>";
       echo" <input type='radio' class='radio-button' name='{$i}'>";
       echo" <input type='radio' class='radio-button' name='{$i}'>" ."</br>";
       echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
       echo" var allRadios = document.getElementsByName('{$i}');";
       echo" var booRadio;";
       echo" var x = 0;";
       echo" for(x = 0; x < allRadios.length; x++){";

            echo"allRadios[x].onclick = function() {";
              echo"  if(booRadio == this){";
                   echo" this.checked = false;";
                  echo"  booRadio = null;";
              echo"  }else{";
                   echo" booRadio = this;";
                echo"}";
           echo" };";
      echo"  }";
    echo"</script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Pro tip: you can jump in and out of "php mode" using `?> your html <?php` to make the above less horrible and actually somewhat readable

Comment: it is an old code, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Can you use jQuery? You can set a listener on your radio buttons that fires an ajax call when they change.

```
$('input[type="radio"].change(function() {
  $.ajax(url, options);
});
```

For specifics on ajax, check out the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/